# Can I create editable text linked to other parts of the document?

Tags: windows, microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2016

I would like to create a text that I can reuse and edit anywhere in the document. Is this possible?

Think of what I want to do as something similar to Insert > Quick Parts > Document Properties > Author. This creates an editable text object that can be modified anywhere in the document.

If possible, I would like to avoid using document properties, as it doesn't really make sense to add this to the document properties. Also, quick parts don't work with custom properties. References to bookmark don't seem like a good solution as they don't seem to provide the editing part.

**Imaginary example**:
In a document, I have a list of tools in a table. In other parts of the document, I have assembling instructions that make use of these tools. In these assembly instructions, I want to reference these tools but also be able to edit them in case I realize for example that I've been using the word "Hammer" but I actually wanted to say "Upholstery hammer" for the entire document, so I just change it in the assembly instructions and it changes everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Alternative way here, although I'm pretty sure, such a "two-way-binding" does not work without plugins with custom properties. However, see an alternative at the end.

Well that's not too difficult

First we need to prepare your list.
Note: I can only verify this for Office 2016 in particular. However, other versions should work similar.

1. (Usually) In your appendices write the list of your tools. One point for each of them (numbering or similar, whatever you see fit).
2. Go to the "Insert"-Tab, then click "Bookmark".
3. Define a meaningful name for your entry (no spaces allowed here, this can be shorter than your actual content).
4. Do this for each of your items separately.

Now, to reference to your tools throughout your document:

1. Place the cursor where you want to insert a reference to one of your tools.
2. Again, in the "Insert"-Tab, click on "Cross Reference".
3. From the left dropdown, select "Bookmark".
4. You should now see a list of available bookmark names in your document. Note, this is not the actual text, but the names you defined earlier (so you can easily refer to entire paragraphs defined in a central place). Select the desired one.
5. In the right dropdown, check that "Bookmark text" is selected.
6. Confirm your choices. You should now see the text is inserted.

Now, when you change something in the tool list, you have to update your fields. Usually I do this with CTRL+A (selecting all text in the document) and then F9 (updating all fields). This might prompt you for your TOC also (and other indexes), if present.

---

Alternative way to the above one (although not really recommended in my oppinion for this case).

1. In the "File"-Tab go to "Info"
2. On the right-hand click on the error next to "Properties", then "Advanced Properties"
3. In the "Custom"-tab you can define your own properties. Not really different to bookmarks in your case most likely.
4. Back in the editing panel, go to the "Insert"-Tab
5. Then go to "Quick Parts" - "Field"
6. In the left dropdown, select "DocProperty"
7. In the right list search for your custom property. Confirm your selection.
8. The value of your custom property is inserted.

However, this does still not create the "two-way-binding" you apparently want. By default (and as far as I know without using VBA code/plugins) this sort of function does only work with the default properties that are already included in Word.

And as a sidenote: From a writers perspective, I think a document where fields are hidden somewhere is a bad choice. I wrote Operating instructions that required FDA compliance. Even without, some notices about order no. or similar topics might be appropriate for each tool if required (ofc depending on the use case).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However unless I'm missing something, you can only edit the text from the reference list. If you change something in the tool name from the assembly instruction and then update it, it will revert to the value in the appendice

Comment: References are supposed to be changed in one central place. Why not change the value in the appendice then?

Comment: Because I don't want them to be in a central place ;) It's a matter of workflow, if I realize the value is wrong, I need to go to the appendice and then update. Or if I realize I need to add another tool, I need to go to the appendice, come back, insert ref. Instead of adding object and inserting this elsewhere.

Comment: Think of what I want to do as Insert > Quick Parts > Document Properties > Author. This creates an editable text object that can be modified anywhere in the document.

Comment: Hmm, now I'm getting it- Difficult one. And it works with the property you described because it's a default one. Think about the effect of having dozens of tools in a long document where all is bind in two ways. Pretty sure, this is still possible but (also pretty sure) not without some custom VBA.

Comment: I feared so... Thank you for helping me with that again